# Proving the equivalence without making use of Truth Tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

How would I prove this without using the truth table? If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated

$$(¬A \lor B) \lor (¬B \lor ¬A) ≡ ¬A$$

This is what I got so far and I'm stuck after this

$$(A → B) \lor ¬(A \land B) ≡ ¬A$$

Comment: By associativity and commutativity $\,(¬A \lor B) \lor (¬B \lor ¬A) = (¬A \lor ¬A) \lor ( \color{blue}{B \lor  ¬B}) ≡ \color{blue}{\text{true}}\,$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalence you have written does not hold.

Counterexample: $A$ and $B$ are both True. Then the left hand side evaluates to $(F \lor T) \lor (F \lor F)=T \lor F=T$, while the right hand side is $F$.

What *does* hold is that $(\neg A \lor B) \color{red}\land (\neg B \lor \neg A) \equiv \neg A$

Assuming you made a typo, and that that is what you needed to show, it
is easily shown as follows:

$$(\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor \neg A) \overset{Commutation}{\equiv}$$

$$(\neg A \lor B ) \land (\neg A \lor \neg B)\overset{Distribution}{\equiv}$$

$$\neg A \lor (B \land \neg B) \overset{Complement}{ \equiv}$$

$$\neg A \lor \bot \overset{Identity}{\equiv}$$

$$\neg A$$

Comment: @JohnCasey well, then you are trying to prove the impossible, since the expression is a tautology, which is not equivalent to $\neg A$. It's a tautology since given that you have all disjunctions, you can drop parentheses, and commute the terms, so you end up with $\neg A \lor \neg A \lor B \lor \neg B$ which is $\neg A \lor \neg A \lor \top$ which is just $\top$, i.e. a tautology

Comment: @John Casey Then maybe the problem given to you has a typo...what  Bram28 said is true.

Comment: @JohnCasey Oh! Yes, if the question was whether they are equvalent or not, then yes, you should say they are not equivalent.

Comment: @JohnCasey You're welcome! :) and look at it this way: it's better that you didn't solve it than that you did, for if you *did*, you would have made a mistake somewhere! :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A$- true and $B$ - true:
$$(\underbrace{(F)}_{\sim A}\vee\underbrace{(V)}_{B})\vee(\underbrace{(F)}_{\sim B}\vee\underbrace{(F)}_{\sim A}) \equiv (V)\vee(F) \equiv (V) \equiv A \not\equiv \sim A$$

Answer (score 0):

The expression on the left-hand side is a tautology (which means it is always true). So, the logical equation you gave is not true.

Use associativity of $\lor$:

$$(¬A \lor B) \lor (¬B \lor ¬A) = ¬A \lor (B \lor ¬B) \lor ¬A = ¬A \lor T \lor ¬A = T$$